# Trying to create a Pomodoro in React but stuck with passing props properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

This post marks my first ever post here!

I am creating a *Pomodoro* in React. My aim is simple. I am creating a Pomodoro clock, was able to do this successfully in JavaScript but with React component architecture. But I am having some issues.

So I have App component that has 3 children: `Session`, `Timer` and `Break`

*App component*

```
    let [fromSession, setFromSession] = useState();
    let [isSession, setIsSession] = useState();
    let [fromBreak, setFromBreak] = useState();
    let [isBreak, setIsBreak] = useState();

    const fromSessionFunction = w => {
        setFromSession(w);
    }

    const sessionTrueOrNot = x => {
        setIsSession(x);
    }

    const fromBreakFunction = y => {
        setFromBreak(y);
    }

    const breakTrueOrNot = z => {
        setIsBreak(z);
    }

    if(isBreak === true) { 
        isSession = false;
    }

    if (isSession === true) {
        isBreak = false;
    }

    console.log('from App', isSession, isBreak)

    return (
        <div className='app-background center'>
            <h1>Pomodoro Timer</h1>
            <div className='flex'>
                <Session sessionFunctionFromApp={fromSessionFunction} sessionTrueOrNot={sessionTrueOrNot}/>
                <Timer sessionFromApp={fromSession} isSessionFromApp={isSession} breakFromApp={fromBreak} isBreakFromApp={isBreak}/>
                <Break breakFunctionFromApp={fromBreakFunction} breakTrueOrNot={breakTrueOrNot}/>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default App;
```

*Session Component*

```
    let [sessionTime, setSessionTime] = useState(25);
    let [sessionTrue, setSessionTrue] = useState();

    const decreaseSessionFunction = () => {
        setSessionTime(sessionTime -= 1);
        setSessionTrue(true);
    }

    const increaseSessionFunction = () => {
        setSessionTime(sessionTime += 1);
        setSessionTrue(true);
        console.log(sessionTrue);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        setSessionTrue(true);
    }, []);

    sessionFunctionFromApp(sessionTime);
    sessionTrueOrNot(sessionTrue);

    return (
        <div>
            <h3>Session</h3>
            <p>{sessionTime}:00</p>
            <button className='ui purple basic button' onClick={() => decreaseSessionFunction()}>-</button>
            <button className='ui purple basic button' onClick={() => increaseSessionFunction()}>+</button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Session;
```

*Timer Component*

```
    let name, display;

    if(isSessionFromApp) {
        name = 'Timer for Session';
        display = sessionFromApp;
    }

    if(isBreakFromApp) {
        name = 'Timer for Break';
        display = breakFromApp;
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <h2>{name}</h2>
            <p id='big-font'>{display}:00</p>
            <button className='ui blue basic button'>Start</button>
            <button className='ui blue basic button'>Stop</button>
            <button className='ui blue basic button'>Restart</button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Timer;
```

*Break Component*

```
    let [breakTime, setBreakTime] = useState(10);
    let [breakTrue, setBreakTrue] = useState();

    const decreaseBreakFunction = () => {
        setBreakTime(breakTime -= 1);
        setBreakTrue(true);
    }

    const increaseBreakFunction = () => {
        setBreakTime(breakTime += 1);
        setBreakTrue(true);
        console.log(breakTrue);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        setBreakTrue(false)
    }, []);

    breakFunctionFromApp(breakTime);
    breakTrueOrNot(breakTrue);

    return (
        <div>
            <h3>Break</h3>
            <p>{breakTime}:00</p>
            <button className='ui violet basic button' onClick={() => decreaseBreakFunction()}>-</button>
            <button className='ui violet basic button' onClick={() => increaseBreakFunction()}>+</button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Break;
```

Alright, literally the only thing I want to do is, from App, when I `console.log` as it is now, it prints `true` or `false` which is good.

**I want `Session` to be true by default and `Break` to be false.** So what I want is when I click on `+` of Break and although the `console.log` from App changes to false true. From line 15 from Break component says false.

Why is this so?

If this is false then how come the App says false true?

And lastly, when I click on the `+` of Session, again line 15 from Session component says true, yet App prints false true.

Thank you for reading, I genuinely appreciate your help, I understand my code reflects that I am a beginner.

Comment: You can refer this https://github.com/SandipNirmal/CountDownTimer. It is old and don't use hooks. It is hosted https://sandipnirmal.github.io/CountDownTimer/#/

Comment: Thanks Sandip but I am trying to learn Hooks and trying to avoid Classes.

This just feels extremely frustrating because I cannot find anything wrong at all

Comment: Can you add codesandbox. I can try fix it there

Comment: Alright, I will try transfer the code to codesandbox. Give me a few minutes.

Comment: @SandipNirmal here is the codesandbox. https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-lake-yksse

Dont worry about the Timer component. My only goal right now is: When I click on +/- of Break, the main heading should say 'Timer for Break', and the time should match whatever Break time says, which it does all ONCE. The moment I click on +/- of Session, nothing changes.

Comment: Answer posted. You need to get a better understand of react's *reactive model*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You saw `Break` and `App` say conflicting thing about the *seemingly* same value `breakTrue`. But they're in fact two value. This's because `setState()` is an async function. You cannot expect it to change its state instantly.

En bref, you code execution order is like:

```
[PSEUDO CODE]

1. Break: setBreakTrue(true)
// issue an async update command, doesn't take effect yet.

2. Break: console.log(breakTrue)
// sync func, instant effect, so you see the old value `false` before previous command

3. App: console.log('from App', isBreak)
// exec in the re-render cycle triggered by 1st command, thus reflects the new value `true`.
```

Here I attach a [demoboard](https://frontarm.com/demoboard/?id=4f55bba9-d37a-4678-8422-f67be4338d28). Check `Break` file ln:22, I added:

`useEffect(() => console.log('breakTrue (async):', breakTrue))`

This `console.log` is wrapped inside `useEffect`, thus it exec **after** `setState` command done its job, so you'll see the new value of `breakTrue` to be `true` as expected.

---

Attached is a re-write of this app:

https://frontarm.com/demoboard/?id=aa46b63b-a020-4041-b8a8-14c2174c647e

Comment: thank you for your explanation. I absolutely never knew `setState` is an `async` function. And now I also know that whatever is inside `useEffect` is executed **after** `setState`is finished.

Comment: Apologies, even after understanding that, I am quite lost as to what to do now? I have spent I dont know how many hours on this, my brain is quite toasted right now hahaha, but really **really** would like to finish this today.

Comment: @5ecured I'm rewriting your app to show you some hint. Give me 5 more minutes.

Comment: take as long as you want, I am already very grateful. If possible if I may ask, please make sure the code is as beginner friendly as mine is, just so that I am able to understand it more. Thanks for your help thus far. (Btw why can't I @hackape? I can do it at the start of this comment but after publishing this comment it just disappears)

Comment: @5ecured Done: https://frontarm.com/demoboard/?id=aa46b63b-a020-4041-b8a8-14c2174c647e. Take a look first, play with it. I'll add some comment to explain, let you know when I'm done with commenting.

Comment: Thanks for making the code look very similar to mine. In General I understand the code, except maybe the Timer, but that is another problem.

May I ask how you came up with the decision to use focusState? Is it just purely from the experience that you have gained from working with React?

Comment: @5ecured I heavily commented the `Timer` file, please take a look.

Comment: The decision is based on the idea of single source of truth. If multiple values can be derived from a single source, then please do reduce it as hard as possible. If not for caching-for-performance reason, intermediate states is pure overhead.

Comment: @5ecured I left one feature un-implemented, the switching between session/break states when timer hit zero. It can be done with `useEffect` in similar fashion to the countdown logic. Apology if I took too much of the coding pleasure from you...Welcome to stackoverflow :-D

Comment: hackape, is there anyway to send a private message to you? There is a warning saying to avoid extended comments :S

Comment: @5ecured https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/204774/pomodoro-app?tab=access can you join this room?

Comment: I can join the chat but need 20 reputation points to talk in chat.... :(

Comment: my firefox froze I had to reopen it. Cannot join chat. Are we able to get a new link for the chat?